# Adding another thumbnail to sharepoint picture library

Tags: picture-library, image

sharepoint automatically generates a thumbnail whenever you upload an image the picture library.

Can i add another thumbnail thats bigger and with a different aspect ratio that would be automatically generated whenever we upload a picture in the picture library along side with the one that is already generated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the websized version?  That one defaults to the normal aspect ratio of the image and max height and width of 640px.  In some of my lists i've changed this to 1024 to get a higher resolution image.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt work i need to have another column in the library thats the size between the original and the thumbnail. With the same ratio.